words like potentially or possibly
Claim 1.
A computer method, comprising:
a) identifying a list of matches, the list potentially empty;

What if a competition implements a solution where the list CANNOT be empty? Would this competitor's solution infringe the claim?
The point of emphasis is that the competitor's solution does not implement the "potential"  as recited in the claim.

Do it is an important feature that the list might be empty ?

No, it is not important. The goal is to get matches, but zero matches is merely a possibility.

If I understand your question there is no reason to have the wording about empty lists. If the claim covers a non-empty list and the infringing system even once performs the method with a non-empty list, it infringes.
A claim lists actions, if the competitor’s system performs those actions at any point, it infringes. It doesn’t need to execute the claimed actions every time it hits a particular circumstance. This is fundamental. This issue has arisen in some other questions.
